# How to assign an error message when adding css class validation rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have added a css class validation rule for jquery validator as follows:

`jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
        requiredDatepicker: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        }
    });`

However, when doing this I get the default error messages.  How can I assign custom error messages when using addClassRules()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this generally with the rule set, since class rules are just combinations of basic rules (for example even `required` is *really* `required: { required: true }` underneath) and *those* have the error messages.  To get custom errors you'll have to set them per-element, or use the meta-data plugin to put the rules on the element directly.

Comment: How can I set the errors per element if I am using css classes as opposed to id?

Comment: @devlife - check out the metadata/validation demo here: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-messages-metadata-demo.html it can be used with data attributes as well.

Comment: I must be missing something.  Here is the html for my input: <input class="field datePicker arrivalDate requiredDatePicker departureDate {required:true, date:true, messages:{required:'enter a valid date', date:'enter a valid date'}}"type="text" value="">.  However, it is not being validated...

Comment: apparently that's what I was missing =)

Answer (score 2):

See the [Refactoring rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Refactoring_rules) section on  how to add custom messages.